# python get all subset by recursive function

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, subset, tail-recursion

I made some python code to get all subset by recursive.

if given a data

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
length = 3
```

the result will print all subset at 3 length
like this

```
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,2,5
2,3,4
2,3,5...
```

this is my code

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
n = 5
r = 3 
    templist = []
    def re(max,length,idx):
        if idx == max:
            return
        if idx == length:
            for i in templist:
                print(" "+str(i))
            print("\n")
            return
        else:
            templist.append(data[idx])
            re(max,length,idx+1)
            templist.pop()
            re(max,length,idx+1)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
     re(n,r,0)
```

my expectaion it loop all the possible subset
but it will fail when it encouter call
`re(max,length,idx+1)`
after
`temlist.pop()`

when code enter the second `re()` function
I expected it append `templist.append(data[4])`
because first `re()` function return by if condition
`if idx == length:`

when `idx` is 3, `idx` is the same the length(3).
so the recursive end,run `temlist.pop()` and
it will enter the second `re(4)` function
because I coded `idx+1`

but it will fail
`idx` only be circled between 2~3

so I changed second recursive function

```
re(max,length,idx+1)
```

to

```
re(max,length,idx+2)
```

and I totally broken.

I think the logic I made was bascally wrong.
but I don't know where to fix it how can I solve to call recursive as I expected?

Comment: You know Python comes with [a module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how:

```
def func(data, length, lst=[]):
    for i in data[length - 1:]:
        lst.append(data[:length - 1] + [i])
    if data:
        func(data[1:], length, lst)
    return lst

data = [1,2,3,4,5]
length = 3

print(func(data, length))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Explanation:

1. Define a function that takes in three parameters, the list *(`data`)*, the length *(`length`)* and an empty list *(`lst`)* to store the output values *(defining it outside the function is considered bad practice)*.
2. Iterate through the elements of the `data` list besides the first `length - 1` indexed elements, and append the elements from the `0` index to the `length - 1` index plus the current element of the iteration.
3. If the `data` list didn't go empty, call the current function again, but using the slice `[1:]` to remove the first character.
4. If the `data` list didn go empty, return the `lst` list.

---

Your other option is to use Python's powerful generators. Using this technique, we no longer need the `lst` parameter -

```py
def func(data, length):
    for i in data[length - 1:]:
        yield data[:length - 1] + [i]
    if data:
        yield from func(data[1:], length)
```

Now we can retrieve the permutations using iteration -

```py
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
length = 3

for perm in func(data, length):
  print(perm)
```

```py
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Or we can gather all permutations in a `list` -

```py
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
length = 3

print(list(func(data, length)))
```

```py
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method to do this is by using the builtin permutations from itertools.

```
from itertools import permutations
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
length = 3
res = list(permutations(data, length))
```